# Phonegap Android Admob Vertical TOP

Tags: android, cordova, admob

am using phonegap for android development
and am using admob for advertisement

am trying to set the ads on top of the page
and it's not working for me
here is my sample code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;
    layout.setVerticalGravity(android.view.Gravity.TOP);
    layout.addView(adView); 
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

    adView.loadAd(request);
}
```

it's still stuck to the bottom of the page
please help
thanks

Comment: What version of cordova are you using?  Where is your super.init()?  It's a linear layout so if you want top you add before super.init and after for bottom.

Comment: am using 2.7.0 , i added super.init() after adView.loadAd(request); and the page disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

i solved it
just add the LinearLayout before super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl()); 
Like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;
    layout.setVerticalGravity(android.view.Gravity.TOP);
    layout.addView(adView); 
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request); 

    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
}
```